# How to add a delete button or long press to delete for a CheckboxListTile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskModel>(builder: (context, task, child) {
      return CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(
          task.text,            
        ),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      );
    });
  }
```

But I cannot figure out how to add another button (small x) or a long press detection so that I can delete from this list. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a GestureDetector widget yo detect a long press:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to @DanielBarragan96, you can wrap your CheckboxListTile with a GestureDetector widget has an onLongPress property that you can set to execute functions.

see
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onLongPress.html for more details